# Linear transformation with an integral.

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, linear-transformations

Define $T: \Bbb{R}_2[x] \to M_2(\Bbb{R})$ by
$$
T(p(x)) := \begin{pmatrix}
p(\beta+1) & p'(\alpha)\\
\int_{-1}^1 p(x) \ dx & p(-\beta)
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
where $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=0$.

I'd like to prove that $T$ is a linear transformation and find $\mathrm{im}(T)$ and $\ker(T)$.

I'm going to be honest with you all, I don't have any idea on how to solve this question because I'm in calculus I, so I don't know anything about integration.

If someone knows how to solve this, please help me if you want to.

Comment: You only need to know how to integrate $x^2$ and $x$, because $p$ is a polynomial of degree $2$.

Comment: You only need to know that $$\int_{-1}^1 (ax^2+bx+c)dx = \frac23 (a+3c).$$ Can you continue with the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm going to try to solve it now.

Comment: Hi Nelson. I did some formatting to your question. Also, besides what @Azif00 already told you, feel free to use that integration is a linear map: $\int_{-1}^1(p(x)+q(x))dx=\int_{-1}^1 p(x) \ dx + \int_{-1}^1 q(x) \ dx$. If you believe these facts, the rest of the problem is standard linear algebra and shouldn't require ay more knowledge about integration.

Comment: I have a doubt, if the question is in R2 why the p(x) is 2++

Comment: Nelson, $\Bbb{R}_2[x]$ means polynomials of degree up to 2. That is, each element in $\Bbb{R}_2[x]$ looks like $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ for some $a,b, c \in \Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sketch of the solution. I'll leave some details for you to verify.

From what was discussed in the comments, it should be clear that $T$ is a linear map.

Any element in $\Bbb{R}_2[x]$ looks like $p(x):=ax^2+bx+c$ for some $a,b,c \in \Bbb{R}$. Thus as a vector space $\Bbb{R}_2[x]$ is $\Bbb{R}^3$ in disguise.

Using that $\alpha=1$ and $\beta=0$, you should quickly get that $p(1)=a+b+c$, $p(0)=c$, $p'(1)=2a$ and
$$ 
\int_{-1}^1p(x)\ dx=\frac{2}{3}a+2c.
$$
Therefore, the map $T$ (regarded as a map from $\Bbb{R}^3$ to $M_2(\Bbb{R})$) looks like
$$
T(a,b,c) := \begin{pmatrix}
a+b+c & 2a\\
\frac{2}{3}a+2c & c
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
From here is easy to see that $\mathrm{ker}(T)=\{(0,0,0)\}$, which in turn means that the only element in $\ker(T)$ is the $0$ polynomial (whence $T$ is injective). To find $\mathrm{im}(T)$ observe that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a+b+c & 2a\\
\frac{2}{3}a+2c & c
\end{pmatrix} = a\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2\\
\frac{2}{3} & 0
\end{pmatrix} + b \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}+ c \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
From here, you should be able to deduce that $\mathrm{im}(T)$ is the span of the three (linearly independent) matrices shown on the right hand side of the last equation above.